# How to get the webpage source in ASP.NET C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest, methods

How can I get the HTML code of a page in C# ASP.NET?

Example: `http://google.com`

How I can get this HTML code by ASP.NET C#?

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for...clean up the wording a little maybe?

Comment: @ justin well are you can read it now

Comment: I think what you're trying to ask is "How can I get the html a browser would be presented after requesting a webpage and put it into a string?"

Comment: @ sparks i want to get html code of a webpages  i don't worry about if image is  hidden and some other markup language problem. i need only html code

Comment: Please don't edit in "the next problem" links. Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class will do what you want:

```
string address = "http://stackoverflow.com/";   

using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    string content = wc.DownloadString(address);
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, you might prefer to use the async version of `DownloadString` to avoid blocking:

```
string address = "http://stackoverflow.com/";

using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.DownloadStringCompleted +=
        new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(DownloadCompleted);
    wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(address));
}

// ...

void DownloadCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Error == null) && !e.Cancelled)
    {
        string content = e.Result;
    }
}
```

Comment: VERY VERY THANKS Luke for Help Me

Comment: This will work BUt your page will block until the subsequent download completes.  Consider using the async methods.

Comment: don't worry about it just say answer @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821348/how-do-regex-find-out-all-hyperlink-in-html-page

Answer (score 1):

MSDN example of HttpWebrequest.GetResponse has working code.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If the question is "How to get the code-behind file of a web page", the answer is no.

Comment: @anirudha Gupta Warning: Please note the "IF" at the beginning of Vedran's answer.  Your question was not very clear so be careful with your wording in the future or your questions may get downvoted.

Comment: pardon for it but i not know english well so are you edit my question

Answer (score -1):

If you are planning to do a lot of web requests to access RESTful services, be careful with the `HttpWebRequest` object. It takes a while to be reclaimed, and if you have enough traffic (just a few calls a minute), you can start to get strange behavior.

If you are loading other pages dynamically, I'd recommend doing it in JavaScript.

Comment: i can't know well your answer's meaning well i use it for get html code not for any other matter