# Getting a remote file and fill a dropdown list

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

Ok, I have a silly question to ask. I have to get this [page](http://currencies.apps.grandtrunk.net/currencies) with a jquery function and fill a dropdown list with data in an asp.net form. Any ideas or examples?

Comment: If you want to fill in a dropdown list with all the world currencies you may use the method seggested [here](http://www.prolificnotion.co.uk/c-utility-method-to-populate-list-controls-with-world-currencies/)

Comment: I think it would be more helpful to communicate a solution to this problem in JavaScript and .NET/ASP.

Comment: @JonasG.Drange Yes, I agree but all I did is suggest an alternative.

Comment: @user1288160, Thanks for your suggest, but the focus of the problem is getting data from that webpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it indirectly using a page method in your codebehind, not directly using jquery due to being blocked by x-site scripting protection.

I'd write a simple class which uses a webclient in .net to pull the page contents back and parse the response into a `List<string>` and return to your control somehow. Depending on if you're using jquery/jscript or an updatepanel in ASP.net, you can call the class method from within your code behind method to prevent a full postback and bind/populate your dropdown list with the data.

Example code is in the response marked answered in [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820991/how-to-get-the-webpage-source-in-asp-net-c).

Answer (score 0):

Cross site scripting is blocked by most browsers. You could use jsonp dataype in your ajax request but the target link don't provide this data type. So, -probably- not possible with javascript.

Comment: Aren't there other way to get that file?